# Confusion in the Apple docs regarding app icons

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

Till now the sizes where for the `iphone4` and up: 114x114 , and `iPad` retina 144x144 . this is here :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html

Now, i can see here, something different( 120x120 ?? )
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html

Moreover, every new app i upload i get some warning about missing icon 120 .

What are all the sizes for the icons for all kind of iDevices now ?? is it changed ?

Thanks a lot .

Comment: Thanks so as what i understand, i have to insert in my app icons for all iOS(6,7) ,and all iDevices needed ??

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request to read the documentation for the poster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS 7 iPhone and iPod touch, both of these sizes are required:

```
120 x 120 pixels
60 x 60 pixels (standard resolution)
```

For iPad, both of these sizes are required:

```
152 x 152
76 x 76 pixels (standard resolution)
```

And for all version

[image]

Comment: oh now i am more confused . lets assume that i want to support for all iOS. Now,what are the sizes required for ipad2 and ipad3 , iphone4 and iphone5 .

Comment: and if i didn't set 120x120(got the warning) , and uploaded the app, it will not work on ios7 ?

Comment: to support all version you need to set all app icon that is listed above image.

Comment: thanks, and names ? where can i find the list ?

Comment: ok got it. icon-72 and icon-76 , and the @2x

Answer (score 2):

When using an [Asset Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html) in Xcode adding an asset of type App Icon will actually show you what sizes are accepted (and for which device):

[image: Asset icon sizes]

Comment: thats nice thanks, but u could not understand from it the answer to my question.

Comment: Actually it's right there: iPhone App iOS 7 60pt (at 2x makes 120). So the 120 icon is the one required for iOS 7.

Comment: Also note that according to the asset catalog there is no 60x60 icon needed, since there's no non-retina version of iOS 7 on iPhone/iPod.